# HashMap, return key and value as a list

Tags: java, data-structures

I have an homework to do, so I have finished the script but the problem is with the values.

The main code is (I cannot change it due to homework) :

```
List<String> result = cw.getResult();
for (String wordRes : result) {
  System.out.println(wordRes);
}
```

It have to return:

> abc 2
> def 2
> ghi 1

I have no idea how to handle that.

Now only shows:

> abc
> def
> ghi

I have no idea how to change this method `getResult` to return with the value of the `hashmap` as well without changing the first main code.

```
public List<String> getResult() {
    List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(list.keySet());
    return keyList;
}
```

The hashmap is: `{abc=2, def=2, ghi=1}`
And list: `Map<String, Integer> list = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

Please help me if you know any resolution.

Comment: Can you show the whole code segment? Your question is unclear

Comment: The best person to help you understand confusing homework assignments is your instructor.  It's very difficult for us to know how much you know or what your instructor is trying to teach you.  At best, someone here might give you code that will work, but your instructor can help you understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well simplest way make an ArrayList and add as @dasblinkenlight said...

```
Iterator<?> it = list.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Map.Entry maps = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    lista.add(maps.getKey() + " " + maps.getValue());
}
}
public List<String> getResult() {
    List<String> temp = lista;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that now that you have learned about `keySet` and `valueSet`, your next task is to learn about `entrySet`. That's a collection of `Map.Entry<K,V>` items, which are in turn composed of the key and the value.

That's precisely what you need to complete your task - simply iterate over the `entrySet` of your `Map` while adding a concatenation of the value and the key to your result list:

```
result.add(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
```

Note that if you use a regular `HashMap`, the items in the result would not be arranged in any particular order.

Comment: Well I just thought that there is any chance to set on the same method intead of making another list.

Comment: @Potar The list of strings that you want does not exist inside the map, so you have to make your own. On the other hand, if you wanted a `List<Map.Entry<K,V>>`, you could get it "for free" by returning `new ArrayList<Map.Entry<K,V>>(map.entrySet())`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
    List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(list.keySet());
```

to:

```
    //first create the new List
    List<String> keyList = new List<String>();
    //iterate through the map and insert the key + ' ' + value as text
    foreach(string item in list.keySet())
    {
        keyList.add(item+' '+list[item]);
    }
    return keyList;
```

I haven't written java in a while so compiler errors might appear, but the idea should work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over map entries in order of keys, use an ordered map:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then add your entries, and to print:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Ibteger> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```